# setting currentTime of HTML5 Video in UIWebView on iPad jumps to different time than set

Tags: html, ipad, video, uiwebview

as the heading already says i got a problem setting the currentTime of my video thats embedded in HTML inside my UIWebView on iPad (xcode-Simulator).
For example when i try jumping to vid.currentTime = 7, it jumps to 6,599999947

Means: **The video never jumps exactly to the value i set. It always starts from a different time which is close, but not exact**

In my case i got an array of start and end-times to jump to certain chapters by swiping.

Could that be a video-codec-problem, iPad-Bug, or got any other idea?

Any help is appreciated - Fab